# Odoo evaluate "contains" expression in domain

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-12

I'm trying to define a domain expression with an evaluation like:
A list of elements contains an element with an id.

I need to simulate a contains expression in python with the next domain.

```
sup = request.env['product.supplierinfo'].search([('id', '=', int(zones))], limit=1)
domain += [('product_tmpl_id.seller_ids', 'in', sup.ids)]
```

The domain call where is giving the error. This _get_search_order is a base method inherited.

```
products = Product.search(
                domain, limit=ppg, offset=pager['offset'],
                order=self._get_search_order(post))
    def _get_search_order(self, post):
        # OrderBy will be parsed in orm and so no direct sql injection
        # id is added to be sure that order is a unique sort key
        return 'is_published desc,%s , id desc' % post.get('order', 'website_sequence desc')
```

I'm getting the next error over and over again.

```
Invalid field 'product_tmpl_id.seller_ids' in leaf "<osv.ExtendedLeaf: ('product_tmpl_id.seller_ids', 'in', [4]) on product_template (ctx: )>"
```

Thanks for reading!

Comment: Make sure to use `product.product` instead of `product.template`

Comment: Yes, the error message tells you you're searching on `product.template` and there is no field `product_tmpl_id` on it.

Comment: When a controller is inherited, if I need to add some code in the middle of this controller function, is needed to copy all the code? When I call my inherited controller, this custom code is executed after the base controller does? Thanks! @CZoellner

Comment: What has this question/comment to do with the situation of this question here?

Comment: Not really anything, but this issue has come up by a controller inheritance, so I suggested you would know something about it in Odoo. Sorry. @CZoellner

Comment: No this problem is just searching on fields of a wrong model, nothing more.